# Get elements of a query-set with a jquery get function. Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In my django app I would like to display a text when a user clicks on a button, without refreshing the page. When the user clicks again, I would like an other text to be displayed, still without refreshing the page.
The informations (texts) I wan't to display are in a query set, named "information".

So I would like to know how to accomplish that.

Here is the way I try to do it:

I create a view where I store my query set:

```
    def get_information (request):
         information= Information.objects.filter(object1__id= X)
```

Then I  create a jquery get function (in the template of the page where the user clicks) in order to get informations on this list:

```
    function get_info(){
    $.get('/mysite/get_information', {'information':information}, function(data) {
      $('.information').html(data); 
      });
      };
```

And then I render it in my template with a submit button and a onclick="get_info".

But I don't know how to make the request get a different information at each request, in order that the user does not get the same information twice.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: what would `X` be in the python code?
And what would `information` be in the `$.get` call in the javascript coda?

Comment: That's my point, I don't know how to tell the jquery function to get one element of the queryset named "information". And for the X, it's just a random number I use to filter the informations I want to keep

Comment: Is the information variable in javascript an array? if so you could use `information.pop()` which will get and remove the last item in the array.

Comment: I second Gonzalo, your question is too unclear as to which criterion you use to filter the `information` objects that appear each time the user clicks. Is it like a "click to refresh", "click to view the next picture in the gallery" or whatever? This will determine how to filter the objects.

Comment: No, I have a query_set named information that contains severals information (texts), and the only thing I wan't to know is how I can ask the jquery get request to get one element of the queryset, then an other... I don't see why it's important to know how I filter my queryset...

Comment: @Shikyo Thank you for the information.pop(), I think it's a good hint, I'll try to use it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in to [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs). You could create the Paginator object in your view and then you can display message from the queryset based on the request from the client side. Let me know in case of any issues.